# Difference between Creality V2.1/V2.2 boards? Where to find datasheets?

Tags: electronics, creality

I can't find an official datasheet for either board. Does anyone know where to find this information? Something that has max voltages, pinouts, etc.

Also, what's the difference between the V2.1 and the V2.2?

Comment: Which printer is this? Creality makes boards custom for each printer they make, so it's difficult to figure out what you're really talking about unless we know the actual printer these boards are from.

Comment: Please add the printer type for this board, thanks!

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find an answer to your query? Or photos of the boards? Or any of the info requested in the comments above?